# Why are these dmsetup commands there?

Tags: linux, bash, encryption, luks

On [this](http://www.freeotfe.org/docs/Explorer/Linux_examples__LUKS.htm) page are there examples of LUKS encryptions. Example below.

Why are the `dmsetup` commands there?

What do they do?

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./volumes/vol_default.vol bs=1M count=1
losetup /dev/loop0 ./volumes/vol_default.vol
echo password1234567890ABC | cryptsetup-luks luksFormat /dev/loop0
cryptsetup-luks luksDump /dev/loop0 
echo password1234567890ABC | cryptsetup-luks luksOpen /dev/loop0 myMapper
dmsetup ls
dmsetup table
dmsetup status
cryptsetup-luks status myMapper
losetup /dev/loop1 /dev/mapper/myMapper
mkdosfs /dev/loop1
mkdir ./test_mountpoint
mount /dev/loop1 ./test_mountpoint
cp ./test_files/SHORT_TEXT.txt        ./test_mountpoint
cp ./test_files/BINARY_ZEROS.dat      ./test_mountpoint
cp ./test_files/BINARY_ABC_RPTD.dat   ./test_mountpoint
cp ./test_files/BINARY_00_FF_RPTD.dat ./test_mountpoint
umount ./test_mountpoint
losetup -d /dev/loop1
cryptsetup-luks luksClose myMapper
losetup -d /dev/loop0
rm -rf ./test_mountpoint
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is they want you to look at the active device mapper devices before you run the `losetup` commands or anything else.  Perhaps `/dev/loop1` is already in use.  They don't want you to trash something accidentally if you already happen to be using that on your system.

A quick look at the dmsetup man page quickly reveals that `ls`, `status`, and `table` are all intended for you to look at the various aspects of the current state of the device mapper.  It is always a good idea to look at the current state of your system before running commands that are potentially destructive.

Comment: I see. You mentioned the `/dev/loop1`. Why is `losetup /dev/loop1 /dev/mapper/myMapper` actually needed? Isn't `/dev/mapper/myMapper` created in the previous step?

Comment: I am not sure why they are doing all that.  IMO, they have made something more complicated then it needs to be for some odd reason.